# How to print the even strings and return the index?

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

I am taking a python 3 course and this was one of the questions. I have a bit of background in C++ but just the basics. My code is below and I am not getting back the correct result I would like, I tried to go about it the way I thought would be best without the help on the internet.

```
st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence'
# Any words that have an even amount of characters in them must print index + "EVEN"

listOfSt = st.split()

for index in listOfSt:
    count = 0
    word = listOfSt[count]
    if len(word) % 2 == 0:
        print(word, " is even! at index: ", count)
    else:
        pass
    count = count + 1
```

Can anyone show me the correct way to go about this and any other useful advice in doing tasks with lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` here.

```
st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence'
for idx,val in enumerate(st.split()):
     if len(val)%2==0:
         print(f'{val} is even at index {idx}')
```

---

Output :

```
only is even at index 1
that is even at index 4
with is even at index 6
in is even at index 8
this is even at index 9
sentence is even at index 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `count = 0` before your for loop. And by the way, your `else : pass` is useless, you can remove it.

```
st = 'Print only the words that start with s in this sentence'
# Any words that have an even amount of characters in them must print index + "EVEN"

listOfSt = st.split()

count = 0 # <--- HERE is the change !
for index in listOfSt:
    word = listOfSt[count]
    if len(word) % 2 == 0:
        print(word, " is even! at index: ", count)
    count = count + 1
```

Output :

```
only  is even! at index:  1
that  is even! at index:  4
with  is even! at index:  6
in  is even! at index:  8
this  is even! at index:  9
sentence  is even! at index:  10
```

Comment: oh I see! I kept putting my index at 0 with each iteration of the for-loop! Simple fix! Thanks a lot!